# Aliased subquery not working

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have the following code:

```
SELECT
CU.customer_ID AS "Customer ID",
CU.cust_LNAME AS "Last Name",
CU.cust_FNAME AS "First Name",
RH.movie_ID AS "Movie ID",
MO.movie_title AS "Movie Title",
MO.release_year AS "Release Year",
(
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RentalHistory RH2 WHERE RH2.movie_ID = RH.movie_ID AND RH2.customer_ID = RH.customer_ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) "Nbr. Of Times Rented"
FROM Customer CU
RIGHT JOIN Rentalhistory RH ON (RH.customer_ID = CU.customer_ID)
INNER JOIN Movie MO ON (MO.movie_ID = RH.movie_ID)
GROUP BY CU.customer_ID, RH.movie_ID    
HAVING "Nbr. Of Times Rented" > 1
ORDER BY CU.cust_LNAME ASC, CU.cust_FNAME ASC;
```

I keep getting invalid identifier for the aliased subquery? Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need the subquery.  Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT CU.customer_ID AS "Customer ID",
       CU.cust_LNAME AS "Last Name",
       CU.cust_FNAME AS "First Name",
       RH.movie_ID AS "Movie ID",
       MO.movie_title AS "Movie Title",
       MO.release_year AS "Release Year",
       COUNT(*) as "Nbr. Of Times Rented"
FROM Customer CU RIGHT JOIN
     Rentalhistory RH
     ON RH.customer_ID = CU.customer_ID INNER JOIN
     Movie MO
     ON MO.movie_ID = RH.movie_ID
GROUP BY CU.customer_ID, RH.movie_ID    
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY CU.cust_LNAME ASC, CU.cust_FNAME ASC;
```

Comment: actually that does work to an extent, customer fields are showing as null, may have to adjust the JOINs to fix that.

Comment: @user3015045 . . . That would happen if you have `customer_id`s in the rental history table that are not in the customer table (or if they just happen to be `NULL` in the customer table).  In most databases, you would not need a `right join` between `Customer` and `RentalHistory`.